# jQuery / Bootstrap Pop up window adding Fees to Running Fee Calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Alright for some reason I can not get it to work properly in this example.. http://jsfiddle.net/hwcu7e05/
Basically what is going on is I have a fee calculator that tallies up the fees as the user processes through the form. In the example there is a checkbox when clicked it is supposed to pop up a div and show Fees $225 (it works on my page for some reason it wont on this example) what I am trying to do is add the fee from my drop down that pops open a new window asking if they want to add for that price.. 
I want it to add the price when they hit accept to my running total on the form.. this is difficult because the form was JavaScript and now I am trying to add this jQuery/bootstrap into it. 
Sorry I am very new and trying to get the hang of all of this, any help is greatly appreciated!
PS. Looks like a lot of code but it is necessary for this example (Skip to the example to not have to look at it all :) )
HTML

```
    Check if
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  id="IRF" 
  name='IRF' 
  onclick="calculateTotal()" />
<br>
<select name="SPECIAL" id="SPECIAL">
  <option>Please Select</div>
    <option 
      data-name="Animal Friend" 
      data-img="/images/img/AnimalFriend.png" 
      data-price="30" 
      value="1">Animal Friend</option>
   <option 
      data-name="Aquaculture" 
      data-img="/images/img/Aquaculture.png" 
      data-price="25" 
      value="2">Aquaculture</option>
   <option 
      data-name="Protect Our Oceans" 
      data-img="/images/img/ProtectOurOceans.png" 
      data-price="20" 
      value="3">Protect Our Oceans</option>
</select>
      <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_special" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Specialty Plate</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary accept">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Display Fees HTML

```
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery/BootStrap

```
function initialRegFee()
{
    var initialFee=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["form"];
    var iRF = theForm.elements["IRF"];
    if(iRF.checked==true)
    {
        initialFee=225;
    }
    return initialFee;
}

function calculateTotal()
{

    var titleFees = initialRegFee();

    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Estimated Transfer Fees $"+titleFees;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}

$(function() {
        $('#SPECIAL').on('change', function() {
            if ($('option:selected', this).is('[data-img]')) {

                $('#modal_special').find('.modal-title').html($('option:selected', this).data('name'));
                $('#modal_special').find('.modal-body').html('')
                .append('<img alt="coming soon" src="' + $('option:selected', this).data('img') + '"/><br/><br/>                 Would you like to add this license plate for: $' + $('option:selected', this).data('price') + ' ?')
                .end().modal('show');
            }
        });

        $('.accept').on('click',function() {
            //do something
            $('#modal_special').modal('hide');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but I don't see any form tags in your HTML, so that might have something to do with it...and also you have `<div id="totalPrice"></div>` before and after your modal in the jsfiddle. And where are you calling `hideTotal()` and `calculateTotal()`?

EDIT:

This worked for me in the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hwcu7e05/5/

I removed the onclick from the input tag at the top of the html and then changed the JavaScript to this:

```
var specialFee = 0;

$(function(){   //added by me
        $('#IRF').click(function(){   
           calculateTotal();   
        });
    });


function initialRegFee()
{
    var initialFee=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["form"];
    var iRF = document.getElementById('IRF');
    if(iRF.checked==true)
    {
        initialFee=225;
    }
    return initialFee;
}

function calculateTotal()
{

    var titleFees = initialRegFee();
    titleFees += specialFee;


    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Estimated Transfer Fees $"+titleFees;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}

$(function() {
        $('#SPECIAL').on('change', function() {
            if ($('option:selected', this).is('[data-img]')) {

                $('#modal_special').find('.modal-title').html($('option:selected', this).data('name'));
                $('#modal_special').find('.modal-body').html('')
                .append('<img alt="coming soon" src="' + $('option:selected', this).data('img') + '"/><br/><br/>                 Would you like to add this license plate for: $' + $('option:selected', this).data('price') + ' ?')
                .end().modal('show');
            }
        });

        $('.accept').on('click',function() {
            specialFee = $('option:selected').data('price');
            calculateTotal();
            $('#modal_special').modal('hide');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Try changing `var iRF = theForm.elements["IRF"];` to `var iRF = getElementById("IRF");`

Comment: `var titleFees = initialRegFee();
var specialFees = <whichever special is selected>;
titleFees += specialFees;`

Something like that?

Comment: Delete all the JS in the fiddle and then copy and paste everything in my edit, it works fine.

Comment: I just repasted my JS code, try it again. It works on my end: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/hwcu7e05/5/